# How to push data to ios application

Tags: ios, swift, mobile, apple-push-notifications

I have a native ios app that is essentially a REST client. The backend is a java REST API.
There is a delegate service that the backend is subscribed to. The delegate service sends events to the backend service.
What is the best way to communicate these events back to the IOS app?
Is polling the only option or is there a cleaner and more efficient way to PUSH data back to the devices.
I have done a little reading about push notifications but I am not sure it fits my use case. I don't want to notify the user about the change, I want the data to be passed to the application and to be used to perform business logic (change the u.i)

Comment: Notifications don't have to have a UI component (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/pushing_background_updates_to_your_app). You could also consider using WebSockets (https://www.raywenderlich.com/13209594-an-introduction-to-websockets)

Comment: I think creating a websocket helps you to get what you need. For instance, you can watch the link above to understand how a reactive backend works. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ewpJ9EUAz5s.